# Block user from entering letters

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a menu that switch the options by pressing the UpArrow and the DownArrow, i want to prevent the user from entering letters or numbers or any key that print something on the screen.

I was thinking to set the cursor position at the end of the text and than print a white space but it prints the letter after the white space, maybe if there's an event that occurs after the letter is printed on screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you only want to allow the up and down arrow and Enter, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Console.ReadKey(intercept: true)` to get a key without echoing it to the console.